# I want to delete specific record in localStorage in Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I am trying to do the following in Selenium IDE in Firefox:

I have a key named dismissGraphHelp in my localStorage.
I am trying to remove it in the script, but it does nothing.

```
getEval (with target) localStorage.removeItem('dismissGraphHelp');
```

How to achieve deleting the key?

If it would be possible, I would love to purge everything the localStorage.

Answer (score 2):

OK, found it.
To purge the localStorage under Selenium IDE/Firefox I did the following:

```
Command: getEval
Target: window.localStorage.clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version of Selenium IDE this appears to have changed from getEval to run script. The command is still as Kokesh posted above.

```
Command: run script
Target: window.localStorage.clear();
```